# convert large data in json format

Tags: php, json

i have a table named  mobile in which all the mobile data is contained which have more then 7000 records now i want to display in json format but some how records are not showing here is my code kindly check ..

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die ("Error ".mysqli_error($conn));
$sql = "select * from mobile";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("error" . mysqli_error($conn));
var_dump($result);

$myArray = array();


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $myArray[] = $row;


}


mysqli_close($conn);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

//$json = file_get_contents('json.json');

/*

$myArray = array("user1" => array("firstName" => "Mike2", "lastName" => "Smith" , "age" => 34),"user2" => array("firstName" => "Mike2", "lastName" => "Smith" , "age" => 34));

*/

$json = json_encode($myArray);

echo $json;


?>
```

table

[image]

Comment: Plz use `json_last_error_msg()/json_last_error()` to check for error while encoding. since no error is shown here, nobody can help.

Comment: thats the problem sir no error is showing .. where doing small data conversion there is no problem but its come to large data . Nothing display

Comment: Remove var_dump($result); if this is an AJAX call and try again then.

Comment: @Indian Thinking check the sourcecode in the webbrowser ;-) May test with: `text/json`, better for so mutch data

Comment: nothing make any difference while removing the var_dump

Comment: @IndianThinking I tried it on my machine with a db and it worked fine. Can you send your database table "mobile"

Comment: wait i post the ss of that

Comment: Can you send a dump of this table? @IndianThinking

Comment: Send your mail id .. will send you soon

Comment: Email it to me at "emails.satish[at]gmail[dot]com"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139367/discussion-between-satish-saini-and-indian-thinking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with JSON_ENCODE in PHP is, it tends to add double quotes and escaping sequences which would increase the actual size of the JSON being imported. So, please try this. This worked for me.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die ("Error ".mysqli_error($conn));
$sql = "select * from mobile";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("error" . mysqli_error($conn));

$myArray = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $myArray[] = $row;
}

mysqli_close($conn);

$prefix = '';
echo '[';
foreach($myArray as $row) {
  echo $prefix, json_encode($row);
  $prefix = ',';
}
echo ']';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are probably using ajax to get your data in the browser you have used a `var_dump()` in your php code followed by the json headers followed by the json result which will not work.

In order to set headers , the `header()` function should be called first before printing out any other thing, also you do no need to put in the var dump. Try the following code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die ("Error ".mysqli_error($conn));
$sql = "select * from mobile";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("error" . mysqli_error($conn));
$myArray = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $myArray[] = $row;
}
mysqli_close($conn);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$json = json_encode($myArray);
echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: - - Hawkeye ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following way:

```
var obj = JSON.parse($myArray);
echo obj;
```